# locust load testing appropiate Number of users to simulate and hatch rate

Tags: locust

I am doing load testing using locust. I write a script and set up everything for load testing.

Only two points I do not understand actually,

**What is the meaning of the below numbers**? e.g

1. **Number of total users to simulate**
2. **Hatch rate (users spawned/second)**

What will be the appropriate value for these two options?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. The number of users: the number of users testing your application. Each user opens a TCP connection to your application and tests it.
2. Hatch rate: For each second, how many users will be added to the current users until the total amount of users. Each hatch Locust calls the on_start function if you have.

**for example:**

- Number of users: 1000
- Hatch rate: 10

Each second 10 users added to current users starting from 0 so in 100 seconds you will have 1000 users. When it reaches to the number of users, the statistic will be reset.

Comment: So, is it like after resetting it will start hitting request again?

Comment: @user3260373 yes until you stop it.

Comment: Is there a way to control the rate of requests per user? or is that always done in a blocking fashion?

Comment: It tries to distribute the load equally for each user. Instead, you can give weight for the tasks, not the users.